# mwe Package additional feature

Tags: discussion

I was looking at the [`mwe`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mwe) package (I haven't tested it) and I was thinking if you can have the same effect of syntax coloring and indentation as it is here in [tex.stackexchange.com](http://tex.stackexchange.com). For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello World!
\end{document}
```

If you notice the code is automatically colored and highlighted with possible line numbering just like the packages that deal with algorithms. Is this a possible addition or does it answer a different purpose from the `mwe` package?

Comment: How does one get TeX syntax highlighting on Meta? The usual `<!-- language: lang-tex -->` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Caramdir It doesn't. I thought it would but I was generally speaking about tex.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Caramdir: There is no syntax highlighting on meta sites.

Comment: While I hope @Martin's explanation helped you, I'm afraid this question is off-topic since it is about a CTAN-package (which a mod here happened to write) and not about a feature of Stack Exchange. Voted to close.

Comment: When someone is writing a piece of code in LaTeX to explain something, whatever it may be, if the mwe provides environments which the user can use, it would make it easier. I see that many users here talk about ways of presenting there code etc. Why not incorporate it to the mwe. Probably its far-fetched but plausible. Just saying.

Answer (score 3):

The `mwe` package is to help creating minimal working examples (MWE), not for displaying them. You can have syntax highlighting and line numbering of LaTeX source code in your document using the `listings` package. The relevant options are `language=[latex]tex` and `numbers=left`. Note that this is about source code in listings as part of your document, not for highlighting the source code in your LaTeX editor.

Comment: I understand its not for highlighting of the source code but when you compile, the pdf output would have the highlighted code as per tex.stackexchange.com. Its just a suggestion and while there are existing packages that may aid in it, why not create a unique display from the others in your package?

Comment: The `mwe` doesn't include any source code in the output.

Comment: The purpose of `mwe` package is to help to create MWEs, you highlight the code of the MWE by posting it in a question or answer.